# Run CMD in a specific folder path as an administrator in windows 11

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator, windows-11-v22h2

I'm was trying to run CMD in a specific folder path but as an administrator in my new windows 11 laptop, in the older windows versions there was the option to open the desired folder and then hold shift + right mouse click and "run CMD here as an administrator" would show up there in the context menu, but now with the new terminal and the new context menu for windows 11 it's all different. I also tried typing "cmd" in the location bar of windows explorer which does open cmd but I couldn't figure out how to make it run it as an Administrator.

Eventually, I worked my brain out and made a copy of cmd.exe from System32 to the desired folder and ran it as an administrator and luckily it worked, but I was hoping for a more convenient way of doing that if anyone could help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is standard "cd" command somehow not working?
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cd-cmd-command/

Comment: If you look around you'll notice this question has been asked over and over throughout the years on Win7/8/10 and now 11. It seems there has never been a convenient way to launch cmd as admin when typing it directly into the address bar of your working directory. It does seem rather odd. There are various solutions out there though, and you appear to have implemented one already. Others also involve registry tweaks that force cmd to open as admin every time globally across the system. These tweaks are all you have your current disposal I'm afraid mate.

Comment: @Aramil I was looking for something that does this function on the internet but I couldn't actually find it (maybe I didn't know how to describe it to google), although it's still not how I would really love but it's better than copying the cmd to folders every time I'm trying to run it as an administrator.

Thank you!

Comment: @Mastaxx Thank you for your reply. I was hoping that Microsoft did actually implement a way to do that that I was unaware of, I was thinking maybe I could open cmd in a specific directory then type a command to restart it with administrator privileges.

I was also trying to find a way to use "cd" command (that the Aramil provided me with) but my search through google didn't get me the answer, probably because of my limited English knowledge.

Anyway, I greatly appreciate your reply and I would look into those on the internet.